# In a horizontally scalable architecture, how to deal with database concurrency when multiple instances read/write to the same row simultaneously?

Tags: database, concurrency, nosql, horizontal-scaling, aws-documentdb

I know SQL Server is very robust in this sense (transactions and locking), but how would that work with NoSQL databases like AWS DocumentDB with Mongo API?

Comment: If you're asking a out Mongo or AWS why tag SQL Server and not Mongo and NoSQL?

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut to diving in and learning each individual systems concurrency model and offerings :/

These guarentees can be found by searching for "Isolation Levels" Or "Default Isolation Levels" for your target database.

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/xact-read-committed.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

One thing to note is that the MySQL and PostgreSQL default isolation level is ["Read Committed"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/xact-read-committed.html).  Which actually can lead to incorrect applications in concurrent environments for common types of queries.

For example if you have a multi threaded web application which allows users to set to their account balance. If both threads fetch the account balance this will result in a logical race where the last thread ends up overwriting the result of first thread.  This is described in detail in each of the documents above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310302/prevent-concurrency-in-nodejs/59313157#59313157

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon DocumentDB, all CRUD statements (findAndModify, update, insert, delete) guarantee atomicity and consistency, even for operations that modify multiple documents. For more information, see [Implicit Transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.implicit-transactions).

Additionally, reads from an Amazon DocumentDB cluster’s primary instance are strongly consistent under normal operating conditions and have read-after-write consistency. For more information, see [Read Preference Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#durability-consistency-isolation).